# Tomcat Server Loaded errir

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-ec2

I tried to install and start the Tomcat on my AWS EC2 instance.
However, I failed to run tomcat server after installed it.
I followed the following article for that
https://blog.devops4me.com/aws-tutorial-how-to-install-tomcat-in-aws-ec2-install/

And after finished step 6, and reloaded tomcat server, I tried to restart tomcat service like step 7. However, my terminal showed as below:

```
Feb 14 20:17:07 ip-172-31-54-104.ec2.internal systemd[1]: tomcat.service: control process exited, code=exited status=203
Feb 14 20:17:07 ip-172-31-54-104.ec2.internal systemd[1]: Failed to start Tomcat Server.
Feb 14 20:17:07 ip-172-31-54-104.ec2.internal systemd[1]: Unit tomcat.service entered failed state.
Feb 14 20:17:07 ip-172-31-54-104.ec2.internal systemd[1]: tomcat.service failed.
Feb 14 20:17:10 ip-172-31-54-104.ec2.internal systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service:22] Missing '='.
Feb 14 20:17:22 ip-172-31-54-104.ec2.internal systemd[1]: tomcat.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Feb 14 20:17:22 ip-172-31-54-104.ec2.internal systemd[1]: tomcat.service failed to schedule restart job: Unit is not loaded properly: Bad message.
Feb 14 20:17:22 ip-172-31-54-104.ec2.internal systemd[1]: Unit tomcat.service entered failed state.
Feb 14 20:17:22 ip-172-31-54-104.ec2.internal systemd[1]: tomcat.service failed.
```

I don't really understand how this work, and tried to search error on internet, but still doesn't have any clue of how to solve this problem, if anyone can give me a hint, that would be great, thank you!

Comment: Check your ```tomcat.service``` file, it's highly likely there is a problem with the file. Alternatively you can try restarting tomcat then once it fails again run ```journalctl -xe``` command and check the latest logs, if there was a problem with the ```tomcat.service``` file you will see which line has a problem.

Comment: Hello, I've adjust my tomcat.service file, and now it still failed. However, from the information it provided. 
It showed.
Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2023-02-14 22:18:33 UTC; 7s ago
  Process: 9367 ExecStart=/usr/local/tomcat9/bin/catalina.sh start (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Comment: could you please provide your ```tomcat.service``` file also what's the output of ```journalctl -xeu tomcat```

Comment: Hello, I found out the problem. And thank you for the idea of direction of solutions

Comment: However now, I am facing another problem, which is when I tried to restart the tomcat server, it showed
Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/local/tomcat9/bin/catalina.sh: Permission denied

Comment: hello, make sure that the tomcat user and group that you set in the ```tomcat.service``` file have the correct permissions to the ```/usr/local/tomcat9/bin``` directory.

Comment: Yes, thank you for helping me solving this problem. It worked!